# Generate dummy according to quanteda dictionary lookup

Tags: r, dictionary, dummy-variable, quanteda

I'm using quanteda to create dictionaries and look up for terms.

Here is a reproducible example of my data:

```
    dput(tweets[1:4, ])
structure(list(tweet_id = c("174457180812_10156824364270813", 
"174457180812_10156824136360813", "174457180812_10156823535820813", 
"174457180812_10156823868565813"), tweet_message = c("Climate change is a big issue", 
"We should care about the environment", "Let's rethink environmental policies", 
"#Davos WEF"
), date = c("2019-03-25T23:03:56+0000", "2019-03-25T21:10:36+0000", 
"2019-03-25T21:00:03+0000", "2019-03-25T20:00:03+0000"), group = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is how I use my dictionary following a suggestion I got from this forum:

```
climate_corpus <- corpus(tweets, text_field = "tweet_message")

climatechange_dict <- 
    dictionary(list(climate = c("environment*", "climate change")))

groupeddfm <- tokens(climate_corpus) %>%
    tokens_lookup(dictionary = climatechange_dict) %>%
    dfm(groups = "group")

convert(groupeddfm, to = "data.frame")
```

What I need to do is to create a dummy in my original dataset "tweets" equal to 1 when tokens_lookup identifies a word included in my dictionary in one specific observation (tweet). Using my reproducible example, I would like to generate a dummy equal to 1 for the first three observations (they include dictionary words), and equal to 0 for the fourth one (no dictionary words).

I would really appreciate your help on this.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.0.1

tweets <- structure(
  list(tweet_id = c(
    "174457180812_10156824364270813",
    "174457180812_10156824136360813", "174457180812_10156823535820813",
    "174457180812_10156823868565813"
  ), tweet_message = c(
    "Climate change is a big issue",
    "We should care about the environment", "Let's rethink environmental policies",
    "#Davos WEF"
  ), date = c(
    "2019-03-25T23:03:56+0000", "2019-03-25T21:10:36+0000",
    "2019-03-25T21:00:03+0000", "2019-03-25T20:00:03+0000"
  ), group = c(
    "1",
    "2", "3", "4"
  )),
  row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c(
    "tbl_df",
    "tbl", "data.frame"
  )
)

climate_corpus <- corpus(tweets, text_field = "tweet_message")
climatechange_dict <-
  dictionary(list(climate = c("environment*", "climate change")))

groupeddfm <- tokens(climate_corpus) %>%
  tokens_lookup(dictionary = climatechange_dict) %>%
  dfm(groups = "group")

tweets$mentions_climate <- as.logical(groupeddfm[, "climate"])
tweets
## # A tibble: 4 x 5
##   tweet_id           tweet_message          date          group mentions_climate
##   <chr>              <chr>                  <chr>         <chr> <lgl>           
## 1 174457180812_1015… Climate change is a b… 2019-03-25T2… 1     TRUE            
## 2 174457180812_1015… We should care about … 2019-03-25T2… 2     TRUE            
## 3 174457180812_1015… Let's rethink environ… 2019-03-25T2… 3     TRUE            
## 4 174457180812_1015… #Davos WEF             2019-03-25T2… 4     FALSE
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! I tried, but I get `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, mentions_climate, value = c(TRUE,  :  replacement has 9 rows, data has 91121`

Comment: I had version 2.0.0 and updated now to version 2.0.1 but I still get the same error message...

Comment: Just edited this to make the code entirely self-contained.

Comment: The codes work perfectly with the reprod. example but I still get that error with the real dataset, with all the packages up to date. Apparently the problem was in making the `tokens_lookup` dividing into groups. I solved changing the code to `%>% dfm()` without the groups. Many thanks for your help!